# What is the most pythonic way of looping in a list until a particular value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just recently learned about the iter function's second argument which can be used to loop until a certain condition is met.

```
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for chunk in iter(lambda _ : f.read(8192), ''):
        print(chunk)
```

However, since iter accepts only functions, I could only code a similar thing for a list by converting it into a generator function and it to iter. Hence, I was wondering if there was a more pythonic way of doing this. Kindly note I have already seen [Padraic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28969626/8381175) and I am specifically referring to just an equality condition.

Comment: you could do `iter(iter(yourlist).__next__, sentinel)` whether that is Pythonic is not for me to decide

Comment: @PaulPanzer I get `AttributeError: 'listiterator' object has no attribute '__next__'` when trying your code (python 2.7)

Comment: @Vinny : in Python 3 it generates a callable iterator

Comment: Any way to implement this in Python 2.7?

Comment: @Vinny use `.next` instead of `__next__` in Python 2. Python 3 uses dunders for the iterator protocol.

Comment: @Vinny `iter(iter(yourlist).next, sentinel)` seems to work on Python2.7

Comment: Damn I forgot `__next__` is `next` .. thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2):

another approach is with a generator

```
def file_iterator(filehandle, chunksize=8192, sentinel=''):
    while True:
        result = f.read(chunksize)
        if result == sentinel:
            return
        yield result

with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for chunk in file_iterator(file):
        print(chunk)
```